# Proof of $\sum_{j=1}^{p-1} \lfloor jq/p \rfloor = \frac{1}{2}(q-1)(p-1)$ Involving Pairing of Summands

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I've seen the proof of the identity

$$\sum_{j=1}^{p-1} \lfloor jq/p \rfloor = \frac{1}{2}(q-1)(p-1)$$

where $p$ and $q$ are coprime positive integers. This involves counting the remainders $r_{j}/p$ of the summands $\lfloor jq/p \rfloor = jq/p - r_{j}/p$. But when I attempted at showing the identity, I used the fact that if $kq/p = n + \alpha$ for some $\alpha < 1$ (which is nonzero since $p$ and $q$ are coprime) and some integer $n$, then we can pair up the summands

$$\big\lfloor kq/p \big\rfloor + \big\lfloor \dfrac{(p-k)q}{p} \big\rfloor = n + q - (n + 1) = q-1.$$

There are $(p-1)/2$ such pairs in the sum if $p$ is odd, and thus we get $(p-1)(q-1)/2$. If $p$ is even, then $q$ is odd and there are $(p-2)/2$ such pairs, with an extra term $\lfloor (p/2)(q/p)\rfloor = (q-1)/2$. Thus we have

$$\dfrac{(q-1)(p-2)}{2} + \dfrac{q-1}{2} = \dfrac{(p-1)(q-1)}{2}$$

as desired.

My question is: Is there something I might be missing in this argument? I can't find a similar one anywhere else, which makes me think that there is a hole somewhere. But I cannot find anything in my view, so maybe others' views will help.

Comment: if you are not sure, re-prove everything. and $\lfloor x \rfloor = x - \{x\}$ with $\{x\} \in [0,1[$ the fractional part which can be easier to think of (in particular that you obtain $q-1$ becomes obvious, since $\{x\} + \{1-x\} = 1$)

Comment: Actually we shall write $\;\left\{ x \right\} + \left\{ {1 - x} \right\} = 1 - \left[ {0 = \left\{ x \right\}} \right]$
, where the square bracket is the " Iverson bracket": $$
\;\left[ P \right] = \left\{ \matrix{
  1\;{\rm if}\;P = TRUE \hfill \cr 
  0\;{\rm if}\;P = FALSE \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your procedure is correct, in fact your steps can be reformulated as follows:
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{p - 1} {\left\lfloor {j\,q/p} \right\rfloor }  = {1 \over 2}\left( {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{p - 1} {\left\lfloor {j\,q/p} \right\rfloor  + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{p - 1} {\left\lfloor {\left( {p - j} \right)\,q/p} \right\rfloor } } } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 2}\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{p - 1} {\left( {\left\lfloor {j\,\left\lfloor {q/p} \right\rfloor  + j\left\{ {q/p} \right\}} \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor {\left( {p - j} \right)\,\left\lfloor {q/p} \right\rfloor  + \left( {p - j} \right)\left\{ {q/p} \right\}} \right\rfloor } \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 2}\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{p - 1} {\left( {p\,\left\lfloor {q/p} \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor {j\left\{ {q/p} \right\}} \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor {\left( {p - j} \right)\left\{ {q/p} \right\}} \right\rfloor } \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 2}\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{p - 1} {\left( {p\,\left\lfloor {q/p} \right\rfloor  + p\left\{ {q/p} \right\} + \left\lfloor {j\left\{ {q/p} \right\}} \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor { - j\left\{ {q/p} \right\}} \right\rfloor } \right)}  \cr} 
$$
and since:$$
\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor { - x} \right\rfloor  = \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  - \left\lceil x \right\rceil  =  - \left[ {0 < \left\{ x \right\}} \right]
$$
where the square brackets are the Iverson bracket, and because:$$
\gcd (q,p) = 1\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \gcd \left( {q\bmod p,p} \right) = 1\quad  \Rightarrow \quad 0 < \left\{ {j\left\{ {q/p} \right\}} \right\}\,\;\left| {\,1 \le j \le p - 1} \right.
$$
then the above converts to:$$
 = {1 \over 2}\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{p - 1} {\left( {q - 1} \right)}  = {{\left( {p - 1} \right)\left( {q - 1} \right)} \over 2}
$$

*---- addendum (in reply to om joglekar) ---*

We can write the duplicated summand as
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 \left\lfloor {\frac{{jq}}{p}} \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor {\frac{{\left( {p - j} \right)q}}{p}} \right\rfloor  =
 \left\lfloor {\frac{{jq}}{p}} \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor {q - \frac{{jq}}{p}} \right\rfloor  =  \\ 
  = q + \left\lfloor {\frac{{jq}}{p}} \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor { - \frac{{jq}}{p}} \right\rfloor  =
 q + \left\lfloor {\frac{{jq}}{p}} \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor { - \left( {\left\lfloor {\frac{{jq}}{p}} \right\rfloor
  + \left\{ {\frac{{jq}}{p}} \right\}} \right)} \right\rfloor  =  \\ 
  = q + \left\lfloor {\frac{{jq}}{p}} \right\rfloor  - \left\lfloor {\frac{{jq}}{p}} \right\rfloor
  + \left\lfloor { - \left\{ {\frac{{jq}}{p}} \right\}} \right\rfloor  =
 q + \left\lfloor { - \left\{ {\frac{{jq}}{p}} \right\}} \right\rfloor  \\ 
 \end{array}
$$

Now the fractional part is limited to be
$$
0 \le \left\{ x \right\} < 1
$$

Since $\gcd(q,p)=1$ and $1 \le j \le p-1$ the fraction $j q / p$ cannot be an integer, hence its fractional part will never be zero.
Therefore
$$
0 < \left\{ {\frac{{jq}}{p}} \right\} < 1\quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad  - 1 <  - \left\{ {\frac{{jq}}{p}} \right\} < 0
$$
and the floor of that will be constant at $-1$.

Comment: everything is perfectly clear till the summation manipulation. The part where you went for the x + (-x) and the inversion bracket and stuff, confused me. how does the sum turn into summation (q-1) ?? pls help . . .

Comment: @omjoglekar:  added explanation of steps

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Understood it clearly ! (+1)